# I face error in my IF ELSE

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am new in PHP. I face problem in my IF ELSE. My IF ELSE Statement is not working. I have two sql queries. In starting i have a simple query which fetch `client_id` against `opinion_id` and  store the result of thi squery in a variable `$opinion_id`

After that i have my sql query which fetch the all `opinion_id` against `client_id` which is fetched from previous query.

My 3rd query is for that if there is no `client_id` against opinion_id`with reference to my 1st query than it only print the record against that`opinion_id`

In My IF ELSE I have a problem it always execute my ELSE part if my `client_id` is null or not.

My remaining PHP code is

```
$opinion = array();

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{        
    $opinion[]= $row1['opinion'];
    $action[]= $row1['atitle'];
    $long_term[]= $row1['ltitle'];
    $outlook[]= $row1['otitle'];
    $rating_type[]= $row1['ttitle'];
    $short_term[]= $row1['stitle'];


}
```

Html Code is

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
include ("sqlquery.php");
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="margin-top:auto; width:auto;font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:12px; text-align:center">
<table width="657">
        <tr>
            <td width="225"> <strong>Opinion</strong></td>
            <td width="62"> <strong>Action</strong></td>
            <td colspan="4"><strong>Ratings</strong></td>
            <td width="54"><strong>Outlook</strong></td>
            <td width="67"><strong>Rating Type</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><b>Long Term</b></td>
          <td colspan="2"><b>Short Term</b></td>
          <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="52"><b>Current</b></td>
          <td width="45"><b>Previous</b></td>
          <td width="49"><b>Current</b></td>
          <td width="51"><b>Previous</b></td>
          <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        for ($i=0; $i<count($opinion); $i++) {
    //if ($opinion[$i] == "")continue;
        ?>


    <tr>
           <td><?php echo $opinion[$i]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $action[$i] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $long_term[$i] ?></td>
          <td><?php //echo $p_long_term[$i]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $short_term[$i] ?></td>
          <td><?php //echo $p_short_term[$i] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $outlook[$i] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        }
?>
 </table>
 <tr>
          <td width="225"><?php // echo $liaison_one_chunks[0]?></td>
          <td width="62"><?php //echo $liaison_one_chunks[1]?></td>
          <td width="52"><b><?php //echo $liaison_one_chunks[2]?></b></td>
          <td width="45"><b><?php //echo $liaison_one_chunks[3]?></b></td>
          <td width="49"><b><?php //echo $liaison_one_chunks[4]?></b></td>

        </tr>
 <table>

 </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: deprecated `mysql_query();` functions should be avoided, use either mysqli or PDO

Comment: That's because you THINK that sometimes $opinion_id is NULL, but it is always NOT null. For reasons.

Comment: @Amarnasan then how i should go for that situation?

Comment: You must check the returned values, and act in consequence... Since I can't see all of your code, I can't elaborate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to execute my query in PHP. I just solved my problem by executing of my query.

```
    $opinion_id = "SELECT `client_id` FROM `pacra_client_opinion_relations` WHERE `opinion_id` = 170";
$result = mysql_query($opinion_id) or die;
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$client_id = $row['client_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you write:

```
if($opinion_id == NULL){
    $query = $q_opinion1;
    }
    else
    { 
        $query = $q_opinion;
    }
  $result1 = mysql_query($query) or die;
```

You must have a *returned value* from the query or otherwise in order to use that in the `$opinion_id`. For instance, did you try to echo `$opinion_id` and see what you got?

Something like:

```
$opinion_id = $returned_value;
if($opinion_id == NULL){
    $query = $q_opinion1;
    }
    else
    { 
        $query = $q_opinion;
    }
  $result1 = mysql_query($query) or die;
```

Comment: Its not working showing error `undefine variable $returnes_value`

Comment: @sunny This was not suppose to be copy/pasted. It was a mechanism trying to show how you should use the `if-statement` Obviously at this point, `$returned_value` is undefined.

Comment: Then what i can store in `$returned_value`

Comment: @sunny You need to fetch or should I say _HAVE_ the `$opinion_id` properly before you use it in the `if-statement`

Comment: @sunny add more of your relevant code so everyone can see and have a better understanding.

Comment: @sunny I see. Do you realize that there is no `$opinion_id` but `$opinion` in the rest of your code?

Comment: `$opinion_id` is a variable which store my sql query result whil `$opinion` is a variable which fetch result from my table

Comment: @sunny Where exactly is the part where you have fetched and stored the value of `$opinion` from your table? Which I'm sure is the problem.

Comment: There is no problem in my `$opinion` i have only problem in my IF ELSE.